# Redirect page after delete account in php

Tags: php, session, redirect

I need a little help here. I have a page profile.php and a option to delete the accound :

```
  // DELETE THE ACCOUNT !!
$_SESSION["delacc"] = FALSE;
          if (isset ($_POST ['deleteaccount'])) {          
            $deleteaccount = $_POST['deleteaccount'];
            $delacc="DELETE FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $resdelacc = mysqli_query($con,$delacc);
            if ($resdelacc) {
               header('Location: index.php');
               $_SESSION["delacc"] = TRUE;
               unset($_SESSION['username']);
            } else {
                echo "ERROR !!! Something were wrong !!";
            }
          }
```

the problem is in **if ($resdelacc)**. If this is true, result that the account was deleted, unset session username (logout) and after this I want to redirect the page to index.php where I have the code :

```
    if(isset($_SESSION["delacc"])) {
if($_SESSION["delacc"] == TRUE) {
    echo "<b><font color='red'>YOUR ACCOUNT WAS SUCCESFULLY DELETED !!</font></b>";
    $_SESSION['delacc'] = FALSE;
} 
}
```

My only problem is that this line " **header('Location: index.php');"** (from profile.php) don't run in any case. When the user click the button "DELETE ACCOUNT", the page remain profil.php, then, if do refresh or access another page, is redirected and appear as guest.

Comment: Firstly, put the redirect after unsetting the session. Plus, did you try redirecting it to another page? e.g. `header('Location: http://google.com');` and see if it works? I reckon there is a problem with the way you're addressing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy .. The reason is after  in the resulted output page you can't redirect. so you've prepare it to be redirected after some seconds enough for user to read the result message.

Like this:

```
if($_SESSION["delacc"] == TRUE) {
  $_SESSION['delacc'] = FALSE;
  echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7;url=http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.html"/>';
  echo "</head><body>";
  echo "<b><font color='red'>YOUR ACCOUNT WAS SUCCESFULLY DELETED !!</font></b>";
}
```

that change will redirect to the index.html after 7 seconds.

PS. The Generated HTML result page make it starts by this code after the POST handling direct. (before any echo) because echo will start generating the results page and the only logical place to redirect is inside the **HEADER** before any **BODY** elements

Answer (score 0):

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0";url="/index.php"/>`

The redirect (url) don't run for index.php because I have another redirect before :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])==FALSE) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

but is ok, I put the message "DELETED SUCCESFULLY" in login.php and deleted from index.php . I set content=0, because after deleted, the user will be restricted for page profile.php and need to change immediatelly to another. Due of the verification of SESSION['username'] which can return profile.php, I can not redirect to another page ... is a conflict. I need a little to think better this code with redirects, I know can solve it better :D thanks for explanations and help